# Single SQL query for selecting chats

Tags: mysql

I need to select all chats and right now I'm selecting them using multiple queries like this:

```
        $query_1 = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT chat_id, user_id_1, user_id_2
                                                     FROM chat
                                                     WHERE user_id_1 = '$user_id' OR user_id_2 = '$user_id')");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_1) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
                $chat_id = $row['chat_id'];
                $user_id_1 = $row['user_id_1'];
                $user_id_2 = $row['user_id_2'];

                if ($user_id_1 == $user_id)
                    $user_id_chat = $user_id_2;
                else
                    $user_id_chat = $user_id_1;

                $query_2 = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT username
                                                                FROM user
                                                                WHERE user_id = '$user_id_chat'");

                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_2);
                $username = $row2['username'];

                $query_3 = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT text,
                                                                (SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM message WHERE chat_id = '$chat_id' AND user_id != '$user_id' AND seen = '0') AS unread_messages
                                                                FROM message
                                                                WHERE chat_id = '$chat_id'
                                                                ORDER BY message_id DESC
                                                                LIMIT 1");

                $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_3);
                $text = $row3['text'];
                $unread_messages = $row3['unread_messages'];
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to get all this ($chat_id, $user_id_chat, $username, $text and $unread_messages) using only one query?

EDIT: Added example data and expected output:

```
Table user

user_id     username     ...
   1          User1      ...
   2          User2      ...
   3          User3      ...
   4          User4      ...


Table chat

chat_id     user_id_1     user_id_2     ...
   1            3            4          ...
   2            1            3          ...


Table message

message_id     chat_id     user_id     text     seen     ...
    1             1           4        Hi!       1       ...
    2             2           1        Hello     1       ...
    3             1           3        hi        0       ...
    4             2           3        Hi        0       ...
    5             2           3     How are you? 0       ...
```

If $user_id is 1 there should be only one chat and value of $chat_id should be 2, of $user_id_chat should be 3, of $username should be 'User3', of $text should be 'How are you?' and of $unread_messages should be 2.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: according to your code `text` and `unread_messages` are not dependent on `$user_id_chat`. that means they are the same for all returning records.

Comment: No, they are not the same for all returning records, they are dependent on `$chat_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c6cb/8

```
$query_1 = mysqli_query($database, 
      "SELECT
         c.chat_id,
         u.username,
         COALESCE(m.text,'MY PLACEHOLDER'),
         COALESCE(um.unread_messages,0)
      FROM (
         SELECT chat_id, 
                IF(user_id_1 = '$user_id', user_id_2, user_id_1) user_id_chat
         FROM chat
         WHERE user_id_1 = '$user_id' OR user_id_2 = '$user_id'
      ) c
      LEFT JOIN user u
      ON u.user_id = c.user_id_chat
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT chat_id, SUM(seen = '0',1,0) unread_messages, MAX(message_id) max_id
           FROM message 
           WHERE  user_id != '$user_id' 
           GROUP BY chat_id) um
      ON um.chat_id = c.chat_id
      LEFT JOIN message m
      ON m.chat_id = c.chat_id
        AND m.message_id = um.max_id ");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query_1) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
    $chat_id = $row['chat_id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $text = $row ['text'];
    $unread_messages = $row['unread_messages'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I get error for this query: Unknown column 'c.user_id_1' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thank you, it works partially. If there are no unread messages query returns NULL, and I would need it to return 0. Also, if last text is from `$user_id` it returns NULL for text, and I would need it to return that last text, no matter if it's from `$user_id` or `$user_id_chat`. And also if text is empty, could it return custom text, something like `CASE text WHEN '' THEN 'picture'`?

Comment: It works for unread messages, but it returns 'MY PLACEHOLDER' when `text` is not empty and is sent by `$user_id`. I would need it to return 'MY PLACEHOLDER' only when `text` is empty, otherwise it should return `text`. Also, in `$query_2` I added 'photo'. Could you add that to your query? Thank you

Comment: *it returns 'MY PLACEHOLDER' when text is not empty* show me proof. Provide SQLfiddle with data sample. *Also, in $query_2 I added 'photo'* - that is your job, not mine, I just showed you the way, but I can't write code for you.

Comment: as you can see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c6cb/4 there is no unread messages for `chat_id=1` that is why you got placeholder. So my query works correctly according to requirements provided.

Comment: I get error when I try to open SQLfiddle so I can't see your example. You're right, I forgot to mention that I would need text even if there are no unread messages for that chat. I thought that was logical because in most chats you can see last message text no matter who sent it and was it seen, and also my `$query_3` returns text even if there are no unread messages. Could you modify your query to return text even if there are no unread messages for that chat? Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for update. Now it shows text even if there are no unread messages for that chat, but it doesn't show last text in chat, it shows last text from `$user_id_chat`. In example for `chat_id=1` it shows that last text is 'Hello' and it should be 'Something'.

Comment: but we still have condition `user_id != '$user_id'` that is why `Hello` is the last for `user_id != 1`. So my point is code and query do what we ask them to do. I am done here. If you know what you want - you can think a little and realize that. I should not really create your code step by step, do it yourself please. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 0):

So, you are looking for a way to select from two tables in one query. Then you might like `INNER JOIN`.
Visit this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

**OR**

Make a function to select like this:

`    function select ($query ="SELECT * FROM $table", $limit = 1) {

```
    $row = mysql_query($query);
    // I'm so lazy to type the other codes, just put ur while loop and other stuff(if any) here

}    `
```

This then must be called as:

`    select("SELECT chat_id, user_id_1, user_id_2
                                                     FROM chat
                                                     WHERE user_id_1 =     '$user_id' OR user_id_2 = '$user_id')");

```
select(" (SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM message WHERE chat_id = '$chat_id' AND user_id != '$user_id' AND seen = '0') AS unread_messages
                                                            FROM message
                                                            WHERE chat_id = '$chat_id' AND user_id != '$user_id'
                                                            ORDER BY message_id DESC
                                                            LIMIT 1");    `
```

This won't need multiple where loops.

Sorry for bad code layout, I'm a newbie here.
Good Luck!